I want to get billing cycles in In App Billing Android
Heading ##I want to check on my App launch that is user is subscribed then how many time it's billing cycle is completed. And I also want to know the expiry date or next billing
date of subscription. Number of billing cycles should supose to be in the orderId but in my orderId it's missing what could be the issue ?
{"orderId":"GPA.34-3143-9003-82176","packageName":"com.app.zestlog","productId":"monthly","purchaseTime":1734424020067,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"mcjnjkgakneidmmihidfjkim.AO-bCBENi9puxztYjZRXlWfAODVzmaTHXSxwuQuEkA","quantity":1,"autoRenewing":true,"acknowledged":true}

It is not recommended to post such essential details like: tokens and IDs on a public platform.
